# Jquery problems with on() and multiple bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I have written a Jquery plugin to make it more easy to deal with a Facebook like "like" functionaltiy in my app. The plugin itself works fine so far but now I ran into an issue.

When I call my custom plugin functions I want to basically toggle the state. When the like was successful I change the class from user-like to user-unline. What now happens is that the bound function is not updated. The text of the link changes but when I click it it's still executing like() instead of unlike().

```
$('.user-like').like({
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $(this).html('Unlike');
        $(this).removeClass('user-like');
        $(this).addClass('user-unlike');
    }
});
$('.user-unlike').unlike({
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $(this).html('Like');
        $(this).removeClass('user-unlike');
        $(this).addClass('user-like');
    }
});
```

How can I make Jquery aware of the changed class and bind the correct function?

Here is the code of my plugin:

```
(function ($) {

    $.likeApi = function (action, options) {
        if (action != 'like' && action != 'unlike') {
            return false;
        }
        var options = jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.likeApi.defaults, options);
        return $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: "POST",
            url: options.baseUrl + action + '.json',
            data: {
                data: {
                    Like: {
                        foreign_key: options.id,
                        model: options.model
                    }
                }
            },
            success: options.success,
            error: options.error,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    };

    $.fn.like = function (options) {
        var scopedOptions = options;
        this.on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.likeApi('like', $.extend({}, scopedOptions, {
                'id': $(event.target).data('like-fk'),
                'model': $(event.target).data('like-model'),
                'success': $.proxy(options.success, this)
            }));
        });
        return this;
    };

    $.fn.unlike = function (options) {
        var scopedOptions = options;
        this.on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.likeApi('unlike', $.extend({}, scopedOptions, {
                'id': $(event.target).data('like-fk'),
                'model': $(event.target).data('like-model'),
                'success': $.proxy(options.success, this)
            }));
        });
        return this;
    };

    $.likeApi.defaults = {
        parent: null,
        baseUrl: '/likes/likes/',
        action: null,
        model: null,
        id: null,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $(body).on('click', '.user-like', yourFunction);
```

or you can check if class exists for clicked element:

```
if ( $(this).hasClass('user-like') ) { /* Do your function */ };
```

Comment: How do I pass my custom jquery function to that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different class as a selector for your plugin:

```
$('.user-action').yourPluginName()
```

And add '.user-like' and '.user-unlike' depending on what state you are on.

Then in your plugin code do something like:

```
  if (this.hasClass('.user-like')) ...
```

Comment: I would prefer to not make my plugin depending on some external factors.